# Chi Square, Program R, Habitat Selection, Multiple Individuals, Multiple Habitat types

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am conducting a radio telemetry survey on trout(n=20) in a small stream. I record stream characteristic data(substrate(sand, silt, gravel), cover(wood, vegetation, rock), morphology(riffle, run, pool, ditch, pond)) at the location of each trout as I locate them. I would like to conduct a chi-square test to determine if trout are selecting any of these habitat types more than the others. I am going to be walking the stream and surveying to get expected values for these habitat types. Would this be best as a large number or proportion?

Also, I am unsure on how to bind the expected values to each row and how to have the observed calculated against expected across multiple individuals. I have included a sample spreadsheet below for what the data will look like.

Thank you.

[image: Sample excel spreadsheet of what data would look like]

Comment: Can you explain your sample dataset more?

Comment: Fish 1 was encountered 10 times total throughout tracking. This is for substrate only but i also have data relating to cover type and stream morphology, so there would be 11 habitat variable. In this example, Fish 1 was observed 5 times over a sand substrate, 3 times over silt substrate, and two times over gravel. The same for the other fish as well. There

Comment: I wanted to know about the Expected value

Comment: The expected is something I was unsure of... I was going to walk the stream(start at a random location and take data on habitat available every 10 meters) and gather data on what is actually available to the fish within the stream. I am unsure on whether to include this as a percent or just a numeric value. I feel like I have seen expected values presented as both in a chi square.